# spot size in a microscopy experiment

Tags: laser, microscopy

How does a laser spot looks like under a high Numerical Aperture objective. I am attaching the profile I am getting in my case. Just wondering how can I calculate my spot diameter or point spread function. Should not it be circular in nature ?

[image]Experimental conditions are wavelength 891 nm, 1.27 NA objective lens (water immersion), glass substrate.

Comment: what is the condition of the laser beam you are trying to image? Have checked that it is a Gaussian beam coming out of the source, and is it being focused to the glass substrate? Is the light source actually coherent (laser) or incoherent (SLED)?

Comment: Hi beam is Gaussian, it was checked with a beam profiler. Its a picosecond laser.

Comment: As you said in the post, in the ideal case, the point spread function of a diffraction-limited imaging system should be axially symmetric (circular). So your image shows some aberrations, but it seems the detector is highly saturated in the center. Is there an image with a lower intensity / shorter exposure? Also, are you focusing the beam onto the substrate or just shining a collimated beam?